# How to set dynamically android layout_height parameter to 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a Framelayout dynamically. 
I set the layout parameters  dynamically as below :

```
   float  weights[] = {80,20} <br>
   FrameLayout flayout = new FrameLayout(context); 
   LayoutParams  lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                         (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,weights[i]; 
   flayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The issue here is  I am trying to set the height parameter as 0 in LayoutParams, but still its taking match_parent and showing in such a way that the first framelayout occupies 20 % (actually should be 80) of screen height and 2nd Framelayout as 80% which happens in reverse.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What is the parent view of FrameLayout? (As in.. what are you adding it to.. or are you setting it as the content view)

Comment: Post more code and the xml... I don't see the error in your current code.

Comment: I myself found the solution. The height of viewGroup(LinearLayout) that holds these 2 frame layouts should be set as match_parent. Previously its set as wrap_Content which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the solution. The height of viewGroup(LinearLayout) that holds these 2 frame layouts should be set as match_parent. Previously its set as wrap_Content which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  FrameLayout flayout = new FrameLayout(contex); 
  LayoutParams  lp = (LayoutParams) flayout.getLayoutParams();
  lp.height = 0;
  lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
  flayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```